# To Parse or not to parse the content of the EditText field if the textInput attribute set to "Time"

Tags: android, datetime, android-edittext, textinput

I don't know if I should parse the content of the EditText field called "startTime" if the textInput attribute is set to "Time."

The input keyboard offers the "Phone Number" set of keys which doesn't quite work for entering time (i.e. I wasn't able to add a period [is present in the keyboard] or a semicolon [is missing] as in 10.55 or 10:55)

Plus, I want to know what format (12-hour vs. 24-hour) is used by default.
It's important because then the question of handeling am/pm distinction comes into the picture.

Please include how to "set/fix it" snippets of code with your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a TimePicker?

Comment: Timepicker is not really an option because I aim for a different UX